# Kotlin compiler to JavaScript in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, kotlin, coco

Is there a Kotlin compiler to JavaScript available in JavaScript (like CoffeeScript or Coco)?

If not, when is expected to be available?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently there's no such implementation.

The existing compiler is written in Java. It is not very clear if we (JetBrains) will work on another implementation in the nearest future. On the other hand, we are always open to contributions...

Comment: Are there any plans to port it to Kotlin? (So it may be then compiled to JavaScript?) Or what parts do you think would be hardest to port to Kotlin?

Comment: Definitely, there are such plans, but currently Kotlin compiler depends on a few Java librarie, most importantly — the IntelliJ IDEA's infrastructure for parsing/representing syntax trees, and that is written in Java, we'd have to reimplement that all to be able to compile the the compiler to JavaScript.

Comment: It's not (pure) Java anymore, is it?